# Problems with tag pair in pt_multiselect

Tags: add-on, pixelandtonic

Trying to use the tag pair feature of pt_multiselect (1.0.3 installed on EE 2.5.5) and it doesn't seem to be working correctly

When used as a single tag I get a list of the selected options, however when used as a tag pair so we can tailor the output (and create links) nothing is shown

Works:

```
{regional_links}
```

Doesn't work:

```
{regional_links}
    <li><strong><a href="{option}">{option_name}</a></strong></li>
{/regional_links}
```

The list of data in the admin is formatted correctly with a a colon delimiting the name and the label and is showing fine in the content add / edit screen.

Data:

```
/asia_pacific/index : Asia Pacific About
/asia_pacific/people : Asia Pacific People
/asia_pacific/locations : Asia Pacific Locations
/asia_pacific/history : Asia Pacific History
/asia_pacific/showcases : Asia Pacific Showcases
/asia_pacific/expertise : Asia Pacific Expertise
/asia_pacific/partners : Asia Pacific Partners
/asia_pacific/contact : Asia Pacific Contact
/northern_europe/index : Northern Europe About
/northern_europe/people : Northern Europe People
/northern_europe/locations : Northern Europe Locations
/northern_europe/history : Northern Europe History
/northern_europe/showcases : Northern Europe Showcases
/northern_europe/expertise : Northern Europe Expertise
/northern_europe/partners : Northern Europe Partners
/northern_europe/contact : Northern Europe Contact
/southern_europe/index : Southern Europe About
/southern_europe/people : Southern Europe People
/southern_europe/locations : Southern Europe Locations
/southern_europe/history : Southern Europe History
/southern_europe/showcases : Southern Europe Showcases
/southern_europe/expertise : Southern Europe Expertise
/southern_europe/partners : Southern Europe Partners
/southern_europe/contact : Southern Europe Contact
/north_america/index : North America About
/north_america/people : North America People
/north_america/locations : North America Locations
/north_america/history : North America History
/north_america/showcases : North America Showcases
/north_america/expertise : North America Expertise
/north_america/partners : North America Partners
/north_america/contact : North America Contact
```

I know this is an oldish plugin but it is somewhat useful and would be great to get it working.

I've tried a more simple list of

```
One
Two
Three
```

Which again works as a single tag to output a list of the selected items, but doesn't work in a tag pair loop.

Any help or suggestions on this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grabbing the latest version of [P&T Fieldpack from github](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_field_pack/tree/master/ee2/third_party). It's now up to version 1.1. I just tried it with your values and it's working fine with the tag pair. If that doesn't work please post more of your template.

Comment: Thought that 1.0.3 was the latest and greatest, thanks for the tip